# XPATH - Get src value of a image from an external webpage

Tags: php, laravel, dom, xpath

Using this code, I tried to retrieved the image from a web page. It worked for similar web pages but not for this link. As I'm new to scraping it somewhat hard to identify the issue.

```
       $doc = new DOMDocument;

       $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
       $doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
       $doc->recover = true;
 
       ini_set('user_agent', 'My-Application/2.5');
       libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
       $doc->loadHTMLFile('https://www.net-a-porter.com/en-us/shop/product/veronica-beard/clothing/blouses/isabel-checked-cotton-blend-top/16114163150514635');
       $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
       $imgs  = $xpath->query('//*[@class="Image18__image Image18__image--undefined "]');
       foreach($imgs as $img)
       {
           echo 'ImgSrc: https:' . $img->getAttribute('src') .'<br />' . PHP_EOL;
       }
```

If `dd($imgs)` I get this,

```
DOMNodeList {#1795 ▼
  +length: 0
}
```

Comment: The path doesn't seem to resolve if a user agent isn't provided (which CURL wouldn't).

Comment: @user3783243 could you explain it more? Are you saying this cannot be done?

Comment: You likely need to get the source code with a different method, or from an API if the site offers it. The behavior I'm seeing suggest they don't support this, and doing so is a violation of their TOS. Run `curl https://www.net-a-porter.com/en-us/shop/product/veronica-beard/clothing/blouses/isabel-checked-cotton-blend-top/16114163150514635 -Iv` command line and you'll see the behavior.

Comment: @user3783243 thanks. and do you know any other quick way of doing it ? I'm reaching my deadline. This is the only website that I had issues.

Comment: You can fiddle around with request methods. Once you get the source use https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php rather than `loadHTMLFile`